# I'm having a stream_socket_enable_crypto(): problem

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I'm trying to send mail using laravel notification class and its giving me this error. Can anyone help?

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\n
error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the solutions that might help you.

1. Make sure your configurations of php.ini are correct.
2. Turn off your anti-virus.
3. Your provided account for sending emails is verified.

Comment: It's not deployed on a live server yet. The code was working and sending mails before. But it just stopped working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).